# Adding a Java Library File .AAR in RAD Studio 10 Seattle

Tags: android, delphi, jar, firemonkey, aar

I need some help about .AAR library files in RAD Studio 10 Seattle.

Can I import "***.aar**" files (with FMX applications under Android) to my Multi-Device Application?

I have found about include **.jar** files, but not about **.aar** files. Is that possible?

[Adding A Java Library File .JAR](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/Seattle/en/Adding_A_Java_Library_to_Your_Application_Using_the_Project_Manager)

Comment: What does the vendor of the tool say in the documentation or on the support channel?

Comment: In documentation appears the info that I have put in that link, but it does not meant that I can not import a .AAR file ... due to this fact I have asked here.

Comment: Why my negative vote?¿? I do not understand it ...

Comment: Why don't you try it? Add the .aar file like you would add a ,jar file and see if you can use it.

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/121350/ive-just-been-downvoted-how-should-i-react

Comment: @Rudy Velthuis that is not true! I tried it but I can not add an .aar file because program only lets me add an .jar file. Moreover, I searched here, in StackvOverflow, before than I wrote this post, but I did not find anything useful ...

Comment: @KryNaC: I said you **could try** and see what happens. I didn't say it would work. But see my answer.

Comment: the solution to import aar is written here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65081528/have-a-question-about-importing-3rd-party-android-aar-library-into-delphi-10-x-p in brief take a look at https://github.com/MagicFoundation/Alcinoe/tree/master/Tools/AndroidMerger

Answer (score 1):

According to [this site](http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system/aar-format), an `.aar` file is just a `.zip` file with the contents mentioned (an Android Library Project):

> - `/AndroidManifest.xml` (mandatory)
> - `/classes.jar` (mandatory)
> - `/res/` (mandatory)
> - `/R.txt` (mandatory)
> - `/assets/` (optional)
> - `/libs/*.jar` (optional)
> - `/jni/<abi>/*.so` (optional)
> - `/proguard.txt` (optional)
> - `/lint.jar` (optional)
>
> These entries are directly at the root of the zip file.

So I suggest you use a ZIP program to examine it, extract it to a directory, and add the files you need to your project.

Comment: I have already read that post. But, with that info I do not know if I can or not import a .AAR file to my Delphi project. Thanks for your time.

Comment: You can **unzip** it and import the unzipped files, perhaps. You can obviously not import it directly.